# Unable to read the file in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a project in our university and in order to make it we have to read a txt file(in java,eclispe). I take the file and drag and drop (the method which reads the file they gave it ready to us)  but when I run the program it gives me this:

[image]

I do not know if the mistake is how I put the file in the Eclipse

[image]

Comment: It means it can't find the file, probably because you don't start the program from the directory where it's located. Check the current directory specified in your run configuration.

Comment: use `File class` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) constructor `new File(String pathname)`, and then print `file.getAbsolutePath())` and you will exactly know, where it is trying to found the file
And if you will paste your code example, it will be also useful- into origin post, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folder name above src is non-English so I can't type it out, but suppose it were just `Laur155`.  Suppose that this folder is directly under ~/workspace.  Then to open the file you would do

```
String filename = "~/workspace/Laur155/NBA-5d-17265n.txt";
```

then something like

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

No we must not change the code in the method which reads the txt file
I know  maybe i confuse you but in my university they havent teach as nothing about files

Comment: If you want to add information with regard to your question edit your question